# Send multiple files via HTTP POST with libcurl

Tags: c, http-post, libcurl

I'm coding a C application which uploads a file using a simple HTTP POST request with libcurl. I am able to do it with one file, but I do not know how to upload multiple files. i tried using another method of the same code but to no avail. The code of the HTTP POST is as follows:

```
void sendHashes()
{
    struct curl_httppost *post = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *last = NULL;
    CURL *curlhash;
    CURLcode response;

    curlhash = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curlhash, CURLOPT_URL, URL);

    curl_formadd(&post, &last,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "Hash",
        CURLFORM_FILECONTENT, "C:\\file.txt", 
        CURLFORM_END
    );

    curl_easy_setopt(curlhash, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);

    response = curl_easy_perform(curlhash);
    curl_formfree(post);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curlhash);
}
```

Comment: you call the function multiple times ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As illustrated by [`docs/examples/postit2.c`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html) sample code, and as stated by [the doc](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) [1], all you need to do is to call `curl_formadd` for each file you want to upload:

```
curl_formadd(&post,
             &last,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "Foo",
             CURLFORM_FILE, "foo.txt",
             CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd(&post,
             &last,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "Bar",
             CURLFORM_FILE, "bar.txt",
             CURLFORM_END);

/* ... */
```

Please note that I've used the `CURLFORM_FILE` option instead of `CURLFORM_FILECONTENT` that *causes that file to be read and its contents used as data in this part*. Make sure to use the proper option by checking the doc [1].

Pro-tip: you can easily test your code by using a debugging service like [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) or [echohttp](http://echohttp.com/).

[1]

> For CURLFORM_FILE the user may send one or more files in one part by
>   providing multiple CURLFORM_FILE arguments each followed by the
>   filename.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But whenever I try to upload a big file, it gives me the error: Failure when receiving data from the peer. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Do you still encounter the problem if you adapt and use the `docs/examples/postit2.c` sample code? The latest version of libcurl? Also: what if you try to upload your file to httpbin or echohttp as suggested above?

Comment: Yup Im using the latest version of libcurl, also the code in docs/examples/postit2.c is just to send two files at the same time, I want to send one file at one time, and the other file at another time.