# CURL and sending file to server

Tags: c++, post, curl

I'm writting application in c++ and I'm trying to send image file to HTTP server. I never use curl before and I'm little confused. I found some nice example of sending file here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html but I dont see where they are add bytes of sending file to request. Can anyone explain me how can I add bytes of my file to request, assuming I have read it to some buffor already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "sendfile",
               CURLFORM_FILE, "postit2.c",
               CURLFORM_END);
```

they set file name into variable "sendfile". After it this library works like browser with post-form (you can see description in the comment at the very begining of the source code). So library sends content of file "postit2.c" (you have to read about CURLFORM_FILE).

Also it might be useful for you to read [Send multiple files via HTTP POST with libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025479/send-multiple-files-via-http-post-with-libcurl)